# how to send and receive object through sockets in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my Server class, I want send the simple class 'heee' but each time I connect to the client I get 'users was not sent' from the try catch. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class heee{

   String  me = "hehehe";
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
  ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(2222);
  System.out.println("Listening");

  while (true) 
  {
     Socket sock = ssock.accept();
     System.out.println("Connected");
     new Thread(new MultiThreadedServer(sock)).start();
  }


}
@Override
public void run() {
   try  
   {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(csocket.getOutputStream());

        heee hope = new heee();
        out.writeObject(hope);
        System.out.println("debug line");

   }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("users was not sent");
    }
```

Here I want to read the object in the thread.

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable {

Socket clientSocket = null;
ObjectInputStream in = null;

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket =  new Socket ("localhost", 2222);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        heee nope = (heee) in.readObject();
        System.out.print(nope.me);

    } catch(Exception Ex)
            {

            }

}



public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    new Thread(new ChatServer()).start();

}

public class heee{

   String  me;
}

}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You are not printing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see true reason of error, you need to print stack trace. You catch `NotSerializableException`. Each object, which you want to write or read must be serializable. Add `implement Serializable` to `heee` signature.

Comment: Ok I've made heee Serializable in both files and added a catch and in the client side it tells me that the write is aborted on the server at line 43 which is the run() method this is the first line of the exception  `java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: MultiThreadedServer` and the last line `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MultiThreadedServer' where as on the server side it tells me 'java.io.NotSerializableException: MultiThreadedServer
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)` and continues like that

Comment: If you made both `heee` classes `Serializable`, this exception has not to be.